# how to use value's in yaml file in test

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

```
yaml file

    test:
      example:
         group:
            "\"is_enabled\": false"
              "\"value\":\"OUT\""

@ConfigurationProperties("test.example.group")
data class Filter(val Group: List<String> = emptyList())
    
in my test code:
             @Value("\${test.example.group}")
             var FilterYaml: Filter
```

I have the following in my application.yml and want to use the values in the group section in a test.
I added the @SpringBootTest annotation which allows me to pull in things.

the error I'm getting is Property must be initialized or be abstract

What I'm not sure about is how to put the values in the FilterYaml variable I've created.

**UPDATE:**
in my test I'm returning a null pointer exception and here's what I have set up.

****in my filer class:****

```
@Component
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ConfigurationProperties("test.example.group")
class Filter {
    data class Group(var Group: List<String> = emptyList())
}
```

**declared at the top of my test**

```
@Autowired
lateinitvar FilterYaml: Filter
```

In my test class:

```
        val optFilter: Filter.group? = null
        val Service = Service(
            optFilter,
        )
```

From what we talked about it shouldn't be giving me null right? the values stored in my yaml file should be passed in.

Comment: Try not posting the same question under different titles https://stackoverflow.com/q/74092031/839733

Answer (score 0):

- First, about the property initialization error: You define an attribute that cannot be null, but do not assign it a value manually. It is invalid for Kotlin compiler, which is not aware that Spring will inject a value *after* object initialization. Therefore, you must change your injected attribute. Either:

  - Mark it as `lateinit`, so Kotlin won't complain that a *non null* variable has no value assigned:

    ```kotlin
    lateinit var filterYaml : Filter
    ```
  - Make it Nullable, so it is assigned to null initially (and later changed by Spring):

    ```kotlin
    var filterYaml: Filter?
    ```
- Moreover, you should not use `@Value` in this context, because it is an *alternative* to `@ConfigurationProperties`. In your case, you should just *autowire* the configuration pojo:

  ```kotlin
  @Autowired 
  lateinit var filterYaml : Filter
  ```

**EDIT**

To help clarify how to manage simple configurations, let's add a full working Spring app sample:

First, let's define the application, its configuration and services.
The sample will produce a "Filter" configuration, as cited in original questions, plus 2 services:

- The first one queries the configuration immediately on initialization
- The second one use lat initialization feature, to allow Spring to inject configuration after initialization
  The app is a short-running app that only prints configuration then stops:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct

@EnableConfigurationProperties(Filter::class)
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

@ConfigurationProperties("com.example.filter")
@ConstructorBinding
data class Filter(val groups: List<String>)

// We can ask Spring to inject configuration when creating/initializing components.
// In this case, we must provide a constructor taking wanted configuration/beans as input.
@Service
class InjectedAtInit(val filter: Filter) {

    init {
        println(
            """
               *******
               INJECTION AT INITIALIZATION:
               -> $filter
               *******
            """.trimIndent()
        )
    }
}

// Or we can ask Spring to inject dependencies AFTER initialization.
// In this case, we use an autowired attribute.
@Service
class InjectedLater {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var filter: Filter

    init {
        // Spring has not injected value yet, an error will be thrown here
        try {
            println(filter)
        } catch (e : UninitializedPropertyAccessException) {
            println("FILTER IS NOT INITIALIZED YET")
        }
    }

    // Post construct annotated methods are automatically launched after both
    // bean initialization and autowired variable injection.
    @PostConstruct
    fun printFilter() = println(
        """
        *******
        INJECTED LATER:
        -> $filter
        ******* 
        """.trimIndent()
    )
}
```

This prints:

```
*******
INJECTION AT INITIALIZATION:
-> Filter(groups=[group1, group2])
*******
FILTER IS NOT INITIALIZED YET
*******
INJECTED LATER:
-> Filter(groups=[group1, group2])
*******
```

Then, we can add a test to verify injected filter values.
To do so, we will use `@SpringBootTest` capability to inject the configuration into our test class. We will produce a single test that verify the "filter" confguration:

```kotlin
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest

@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var filter: Filter

    @Test
    fun verifyFilter() {
        assertThat(filter.groups).contains("group1", "group2")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer exception in my test. looks like the values arent passing in. will add a update to my original post

Comment: @AnthonyEdwardsStan : I've added a complete app sample to make more explicit how configuration should be managed. Spring-Boot is a complex beast, you should take the time to read pieces of the reference doc, it is very well done. For example, the part [about type-safe configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties) is pretty detailed.

Comment: very cool in the test using the first example. is it also supposed to be auto wired i want sure if both cases used the same test @amanin